# How to implement recursive method properly?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a list and this is how it looks like:

[image]

I have an `arraylist<XmlProperty> myList`.

My myList looks like this Image, so myList.get(0) ist the first row, myList.get(1) the second row etc.

An important point is that there are myList-Elements which are for example of Type "AdressType", so there are "children"-elements.

For this myList the Relations look like:

```
Stage = 0    Stage = 1     Stage = 2
Adress
-------------City
-------------Street
---------------------------StreetName
---------------------------HouseNumber
---------------------------Suffix
-------------PostalCode
```

So elements of Stage=1 are the children of the elements of the element of Stage=0.
You see it in the column "ChildNr" which elements are the children of the certain element.

So I want to invoke all methods with the objectValues but I have to take care about elements which have children because before I invoke them I have to invoke the children at first.

I tried to implement it, but I cannot implement the recursion properly.

```
public void buildChildrenObjectsRecursively(Object object, int xmlNumber, int fieldNr, int objectLength) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

    //amount of children-elements
    if (objectLength != 0) {

        if (myList.get(fieldNr).isHasChild() == false) {

            myList.get(fieldNr).getCreateMethod().invoke(object, myList.get(fieldNr).getInstance());
            fieldNr++;

        } else { //recursive call

            int childLength = getLengthOfObject(myList.get(fieldNr).getInstance());
            buildChildrenObjectsRecursively(myList.get(fieldNr).getInstance(), xmlNumber, fieldNr + 1, childLength);
            myList.get(fieldNr).getCreateMethod().invoke(object, allXmls.get(xmlNumber).get(fieldNr).getInstance());
        }
        objectLength--;
    }
}
```

getInstance() is the Object in column "ObjectValue".

So where is my mistake?

All I want to do is:

1. invoke method on object
2. if there are children , then invoke methods on children-elements first, after that invoke method on object

**UPDATE**

I have to clarify it.

All what I want to do is:

1. invoke method object
2. if there are childre, the invoke methods on children-element first. after that invoke on object

This means for our example in the picture:

List with the order {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} should be {2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 1}.
So in this order I can invoke the methods with a Loop easily.

So how can I do this?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Are you getting an error? Bad results? This is too broad currently.

Comment: I know that this only can be solved with recursion and my method has some errors. the main logic should be: 1. Go through the list. 2. if there are children, go in the childrens' class. 3.If the field is a primitive datatype, i. e. no object type, then print it.

Comment: I read in an algorithm book (Sedgewick) that you can tranform every recursive algorithm into a sequential loop, mostly mechanically. So no, it can't only be solved in a recursive way - which doesn't mean that you shouldn't try. Just a minor correction of your claim.

Comment: @userunknown my idea is that I Need the recursion to go in the nested objects and I need a loop to walk through all fields. I am stuck....

Answer (score 0):

The data struct define， you need use lombok if you using the Stage class :

```
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class Stage{
    private Integer number;
    private Integer stageNumber;
    private List<Integer> childNumber;


    public static final class StageBuilder {
        private Integer number;
        private Integer stageNumber;
        private List<Integer> childNumber;

        private StageBuilder() {
        }

        public static StageBuilder aStage() {
            return new StageBuilder();
        }

        public StageBuilder withNumber(Integer number) {
            this.number = number;
            return this;
        }

        public StageBuilder withStageNumber(Integer stageNumber) {
            this.stageNumber = stageNumber;
            return this;
        }

        public StageBuilder withChildNumber(List<Integer> childNumber) {
            this.childNumber = childNumber;
            return this;
        }

        public Stage build() {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setNumber(number);
            stage.setStageNumber(stageNumber);
            stage.setChildNumber(childNumber);
            return stage;
        }
    }
}
```

The implement of the stage, just using java8 to sort by the stage number：

```
public class StageTest extends TestCase {
    public void test() {
        Stage stage1 = Stage.StageBuilder.aStage().withNumber(1).withStageNumber(0).withChildNumber(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 7)).build();
        Stage stage2 = Stage.StageBuilder.aStage().withNumber(2).withStageNumber(1).build();
        Stage stage3 = Stage.StageBuilder.aStage().withNumber(3).withStageNumber(1).withChildNumber(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6)).build();
        Stage stage4 = Stage.StageBuilder.aStage().withNumber(4).withStageNumber(2).build();
        Stage stage5 = Stage.StageBuilder.aStage().withNumber(5).withStageNumber(2).build();
        Stage stage6 = Stage.StageBuilder.aStage().withNumber(6).withStageNumber(2).build();
        Stage stage7 = Stage.StageBuilder.aStage().withNumber(7).withStageNumber(1).build();
        List<Stage> stageList = Arrays.asList(stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4, stage5, stage6, stage7);
        stageList.sort((o1, o2) -> o2.getStageNumber() - o1.getStageNumber());
        stageList.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getNumber()));
    }
}
```

Comment: The result should be { 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 1}. But the result with your code is {4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 1}.  So the main logic should be: 1. Go through the list. 2. if there are children, go in the childrens' class. 3.If the field is a primitive datatype, i. e. no object type, then print it.